# How to use color picker with design:attribute in community builder?

Tags: community

I am trying to use the color picker in community builder but it throwing the error when I am putting "type="Color" in the design file?

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="buttonColor" type="String" />
    {!v.buttonColor}
</aura:component>
```

Design Metadata

```
<design:component>
        <design:attribute type="Color" name="buttonColor" default="rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)" />
    </design:component>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"type="Color"` attribute is supported ONLY if you implement `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes` interface.

you should update your component .cmp code as

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="buttonColor" type="String" />
    {!v.buttonColor}
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thank you, It was very quick and helpful for me and I understood that We only need to implements forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes interface we can't use any other interface when we are "type="Color" in in the design file.